# Mosquitto fire only one for each topic

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I implemented a MQTT message broker using mosquitto on my network. I have one web app publishing things to the broker and several servers that subscribed the same topic. So i have a redundancy scenario.

My question is, using mosquitto alone, is there any way to configure it to publish data only on the first subscriber?  Otherwise, all of them will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible.

But you can do this.

Have the first subscriber program respond with an ack on the channel as soon as it gets the message, and have the redundancy program look for the ack for a small time after the initial message.

IF the ack is received the redundancy should not do anything.

So if the first subscriber gets and uses the message, the others wont do anything even if they get the message.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much. I thought about that dirty way. Have you used that way before ?

Comment: Yes I have.

I put the ack channel in the sub-directory of the topic

And since MQTT client gives you the absolute path where the ack was published, I could differentiate between the publisher and the first subscriber.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know any good reading to implement if ?

Comment: Don't know any. Sorry. 
But this workaround is not that difficult to implement.

All you do is pass the ack level as an argument to your code, and have the callback for message received, check for the right ack level with the right amount of delay.

I wish I could share the code that I had written, but i don't have access to it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible with mosquitto at the moment (without communication between the 2 subscribers as described in the other answer).

For the new release of the MQTT spec (v5)* there is a new mode called "Shared Subscriptions". This allow s multiple clients to subscribe to a single topic and messages will be delivered by round robin to each client. This is more for load balancing rather than master/slave fail over.

*There are some brokers (HiveMQ, IBM MessageSight) that already support some version of Shared Subscriptions at MQTT v3.1.1, but they implement it in slightly different ways (different topic prefixes) so they are not cross compatible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I will work on a work around.